# How to show a false as true, and true as false in checkbox angular 2

Tags: angular

I have this 
`<input type="checkbox" [(ngModel)]="!item.h">`
but is getting me errors...
`<input type="checkbox" [(ngModel)]="item.h">` this work smothly but i need to show the false of this model as positive, and the positive as false.

Thnks!

Comment: I don't see what you have done so far, how the code looks where problem is, etc.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think you can try 
    `<input type="checkbox" [checked] = "!item.h" (change)="item.h= !item.h"`>

This way the value will be set right on init based on the checked property, and it will revert the component variable on change

Answer (score 0):

Within Javascript itself you can cast a value to it's boolean opposite using the exclamation -- NOT -- character:

```
var notTrue = !true;
console.log(notTrue); // returns false
```

So, why not just throw an exclamation in front of the variable that would in turn toggle the checkbox?

Though, I could be way off from giving you the answer you're looking for, but I have no code to go by...

FINAL NOTE: The number 0 is tricky because `!0` would be `true`.  Just a heads up if 0 may be a value that occurs.